# Print only contents in infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list, display-form

Still another question concerning sharepoint and forms.

I created a list, from which I created a newform.aspx (For users to register) and a dispform.aspx (For users to view their registration). However, due to data integrity reasons, I chose to customize the dispform.aspx using Infopath 2013.

Through Microsoft designer, I added a custom list form in the disp.aspx page.

My issue is that I want the users to be able to print the dispForm.aspx. To achieve this, I inserted a CEWP in the dispForm, and used the script as follows:  `<a href="javascript:window.print()">Print</a>.`

However, what happens with this script is that it prints the entire window, together with the buttons and the menus.

Is there a way to print only the contents of the form?

I've tried to enclose the form in a `<Div>` and used javascript to print only the Div contents but nothing happens when the print button is pressed.

Can anyone please help me with this?